# Eclipse no me autocompleta algunos metodos en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, autocompletar

Tengo un problema con Eclipse. Llevo 3 años usandolo y hasta ahora no habia tenido problema alguno con el IDE. La cuestion es que me falla el autocompletado pero solo en algunos paquetes de java. Por ejemplo, creo una clase heredada de JFrame y al poner el metodo SetBounds o SetVisible no me sale en el autocompletado, aunque si lo escribo a mano si funciona. Igual a la hora de importar los paquetes. Me salen en el autocompletado hasta java.awt, pero las siguientes por ejemplo java.awt.Window no me salen. Ya digo que si lo escribo todo a mano el programa funciona correctamente pero es el autocompletado el que falla. He reintalado Java y Eclipse varias veces pero sigue igual, dejando la configuracion de Eclipse por defecto. A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Gracias!!

Comment: Amigo tengo ese mismo problema lograste resolverlo?

Answer (score 1):

[Acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/495197) hablan acerca de lo mismo. A mí me pasaba y lo pude solucionar de la manera que indican en otra pregunta de la página.
A mí no me aparecía el autocompletado de los métodos del paquete `java.awt.*` y tuve que seguir los pasos como se indica:

Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Appearance --> Type filters --> Desactivar el check de `java.awt.*` o el que necesiten.

Answer (score 0):

A mi cada cierto tiempo no me funciona el asistente, lo mas probable es que tengas desactivado, o se hallan desactivado algunas opciones en el Content Assist, la solución es siempre la misma, puede ser lo siguiente (probado en la versión Eclipse IDE 2021-06)

Ir a:

```
- Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist
```

Para que se abra el asistente por cada tipeo de tecla, donde dice `Auto activation triggers for Java` escribir:

```
.abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Luego `Content Assist -> Advanced` en el primer recuadro activa lo siguiente:

```
- Java Proposals
- SWT Template Proposals
- Template Proposals
```

En el segundo recuadro

```
- Template Proposals
- SWT Template Proposals
- Java Proposals
```

Esto es para que el asistente muestre clases y paquetes de Swing y algunos Templates de código que hallas creado para ir mas rápido, ademas del código Java típico.

En esta ventana puede que salten un montón de otras cosas por ejemplo `JPA Proposals` si lo utilizas activalo para recibir sugerencias del asistente.

Luego también tengo instalada la versión de Eclipse Luna y la configuración es la misma pero agregando lo siguiente:

```
- Adaptive Template Proposals (Code Recommenders)
- Intelligent Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)
```

Realmente solo hace falta activar `Java Proposals` pero ya que están las opciones...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Con el tema del autocompletado, nunca he tenido problema en que no me salga. Es solo que algunas clases, aun habiendolas importado, no me salen en la pantalla de autocompletado. Las soluciones que me has ofrecido ya las habia probado, pero sin exito. No se que puede ser la verdad.

Answer (score -1):

Hola a mi me paso lo mismo tenes que ir a Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Appearance --> Type filters --> Desactivar java.awt.*

Comment: Respuesta duplicada. Ya existe una respuesta con exactamente la misma información.