# Eclipse no muestra los métodos de una clase en el autocompletado

Tags: eclipse, autocompletar

Cuando trato de acceder a un método con el autocompletado no me muestra todos.
Tengo que escribirlos manualmente ya que en la ventana del autocompletado no salen los que necesito

Comment: Estas programando con alguna biblioteca en especifico? que métodos no desplega el asistente? Eclipse tiene algunos filtros por ejemplo todas las clases que están en los paquetes com.sun.*, io.micrometer.*, java.awt.*, java.rmi.*, jdk.*, org.graalvm.* y sun.*, por dar un ejemplo el filtro de java.awt.*, causa conflicto en el autocompletado de la biblioteca Swing, ejemplo FlowLayout se sigue usando y otras clases de awt.

Comment: Cuando programo con swing. Cuando instancio un Jframe los métodos del objeto creado no aparecen y tengo que escribirlos manualmente

Answer (score 0):

Escribo la respuesta para darte una explicación mas extensa, Eclipse tiene algunos filtros donde evitan que en la ventana del asistente muestre algunos métodos o clases que están en un determinado paquete, esto con la intención de no mostrar paquetes que están obsoletos, por ejemplo las clases del paquete `sun.*` o desde hace un tiempo la librería `AWT` que fue remplazada por `Swing`, el problema de esto es que Swing se basa en AWT hasta el punto de usar clases completamente como FlowLayout y otros administradores de diseño.

También como te comente antes, el asistente solo muestra los métodos que provienen de las clases de Swing, evitando los métodos de AWT, y por ejemplo JFrame tiene muy pocos métodos propios, y la mayoría viene de Frame o de Window.

Para desactivar el filtro podes ir a

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters
```

Y de ahí desactivar únicamente el chack del campo `java.awt.*` y luego `Apply and Close`

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier cosa avísame.

Comment: Amigo funcionó gracias

Comment: @Manuel en dado caso acepta la respuesta dándole click al icono de la palomita que está del lado izquierdo para aceptar esta respuesta como la correcta